# Calendars and Content types

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I've created a SharePoint calendar with content types: Available and Unavailable.  The "All Day Event",
"Recurrence", and "Workspace" fields are not available in the new content types.  I need the All Day Event and Reccurence fields.  I am not using the "Event" content type on this calendar.
Should the All Day Event and related colums be available on the new content types?
If so, what did I likely do wrong?
If not, how do I get the desired columns into the new content types?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Are your content derived from the event content type though? I believe the event content type to be hidden, but creating your content types using a feature and by using the content type id hierarchy to have your Available / Unavailable content types derive from the sharepoint event content type would solve your problems. Remove any fields (site columns) you don't need.

Use the xml snippet below to create a derived content type. IMHO it is always best to first create a base content type derived from an out of the box sharepoint ctype when you plan on creating more than 1 version of that ctype.

```
<!-- 0x0102 is the sharepoint event content type's id,
00 is a splitter, 
the rest is a guid that you generate, stripped of dashes and {}
i.e. {54646609-853E-4f28-B4F8-B6258DBFD632}
add 01, 02, etc. at the end to create ctypes derived from this base ctype-->
<ContentType ID="0x01020054646609853E4f28B4F8B6258DBFD632" 
           Name="Event Derived Base Content Type" 
           Description="This serves as a base for all your event ctype derived ctypes" 
           Group="Group the ctype should fall under in ctypes site settings page">
  <FieldRefs>
  </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>

<!-- by adding 01 you create a new, specific purpose ctype-->
<ContentType ID="0x01020054646609853E4f28B4F8B6258DBFD63201" 
           Name="Available" 
           Description="Your description" 
           Group="Name of group">
  <FieldRefs>
  </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>

<!-- same for 02 -->
<ContentType ID="0x01020054646609853E4f28B4F8B6258DBFD63202" 
           Name="Unavailable" 
           Description="Your description" 
           Group="Name of group">
  <FieldRefs>
  </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```